# Xamarin Forms uwp Asyncronous Socket Communitation example

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am looking for a working sample of a Xamarin Forms Asynchronous Socket communication project.  I want BOTH sides of my project (the server and client) to be Xamarin Forms apps and to be able to communicate between them using Sockets.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS I cannot use web sockets and I want the server to be xamarin so I can use it on MacOs or a windows UWP app

UPDATE - I have the samples working calling from a Mobile device Xamarin Forms app to the Console App Listener.  However, when I try to move the console app code in the another Xamarin Forms app and run a UWP project to listen for the connections, no connection is ever received.  Here is the code:

This is the code for the button in my server app that starts listing:

```
    private void btnStartListening_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening();
        });

    }
```

Here is the server method that listens:

```
    public static void StartListening()
    {

        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection on " + ipAddress.ToString() + "...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I know the mobile app part is correct because it can connect to the console app listening on the port.  Any idea why this code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I figured this out.  This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets#build-a-basic-tcp-socket-client-and-server states

As a consequence of network isolation, Windows disallows establishing a socket connection (Sockets or WinSock) between two UWP apps running on the same machine; whether that's via the local loopback address (127.0.0.0), or by explicitly specifying the local IP address. For details about mechanisms by which UWP apps can communicate with one another, see App-to-app communication.

HOWEVER, this statement is a little inaccurate as far as I can tell.  It does not seem to be only between two UWP apps on the same computer.  It seems to be between maybe any non-console based app and a UWP listener on the same computer.

Thus when I was running my Xamarin project test from the Android Emulator trying to connect to my UWP listener, I could not connect because both of the apps were technically running on the same computer.  To verify, I deployed my Android app to a device and retested connecting to the UWP app and it connected fine.

I hope this helps others as it was kind of confusing for me.

Answer (score -1):

On Xamarin.Forms, you can use all of the regular .Net socket class:

**Namespaces:**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

**Example:**

```
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ipAddress.ToString());
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                             SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml Required Permissions are:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The MSDN-based [Asynchronous Server Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) example works as a cut/paste example with no changes.

Comment: Yes I have tried all that but was unable to get an actual working example in Xamarin Forms which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Also the sample provided does not work in Xamarin Forms app running on iOS or android if you simply cut and paste it - which again is what I am looking for.